# What is the probability distribution of $X$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

An organization has an opening for a position with requirements met only met by $10$% of all applicants. Let $X$ denote the number of applicants until the position is filled. (applications are processed one at a time)

What is the probability distribution of $X$ ? And what is the mean and the variance ?

Is it normal ?

Comment: You have probability of success, $0.1$, one trial at a time, and wait and count the number of trials until the first success. Doesn’t that sound familiar?

Comment: so it is binomial ?

Comment: Close but not quite—Binomial distribution would count the number of successes in a given run of $N$ independent trials and chance of success $p$. Note the difference between this description and my first comment. See Foreman’s answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ here is distributed geometrically. In fact $X$~$Geo(0.1)$. The mean of a gemetric is given by $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{0.1}=10$ in this case and the variance is given by $\frac{1-p}{p^2}=\frac{0.9}{0.1^2}=90$.

Comment: To find $M$ such that $P(X\leq M)\approx 0.95$ , I calculated $P(X\leq M)$ which is equal to $1-P(X\geq M)=1-0.9^M$, correct till here ?

Comment: Yes except you wrote $P(X \ge M)$ when you meant $P(X \gt M)$